# cargo.toml dependencies are ignored?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

(im following [this](https://os.phil-opp.com/vga-text-mode/) tutorial)

For some reason my imports arent working

```ini
[package]
name = "Klos"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["wellsilver <wellsilver2016@gmail.com>"]

[dependencies]
bootloader = "0.9.8"
volatile = "0.2.6"
spin = "0.5.2"

[dependencies.lazy_static]
version = "1.4.0"
features = ["spin_no_std"]

[profile.dev]
panic = "abort" # disable stack unwinding on panic

[profile.release]
panic = "abort" # disable stack unwinding on panic

[unstable]
build-std = ["core", "compiler_builtins"]
```

here is what the Cargo.toml looks like but for some reason volatile spin and lazy_static dont work with `error[E0432]`

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `lazy_static`
 --> src\vga_buffer.rs:2:5
  |
2 | use lazy_static::lazy_static;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^ maybe a missing crate `lazy_static`?

error[E0432]: unresolved import `spin`
 --> src\vga_buffer.rs:3:5
  |
3 | use spin::Mutex;
  |     ^^^^ maybe a missing crate `spin`?

error[E0432]: unresolved import `volatile`
 --> src\vga_buffer.rs:4:5
  |
4 | use volatile::Volatile;
  |     ^^^^^^^^ maybe a missing crate `volatile`?
```

I'm running `cargo bootimage` and `cargo build` and both give the same error

main.rs

```rust
#![no_std] 
#![no_main] // disable libaries (nothing that supports them) and rusty things

use core::panic::PanicInfo;
mod vga_buffer; // print! and println!

/// if computer == pain {
#[panic_handler]
fn panic(_info: &PanicInfo) -> ! {
  print!("Hello World!");
  loop {}
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn _start() -> ! {
  loop {}
}
```

vga_buffer (errors)

````rust
use core::fmt;
use lazy_static::lazy_static;
use spin::Mutex;
use volatile::Volatile;

lazy_static! {
    /// A global `Writer` instance that can be used for printing to the VGA text buffer.
    ///
    /// Used by the `print!` and `println!` macros.
    pub static ref WRITER: Mutex<Writer> = Mutex::new(Writer {
        column_position: 0,
        color_code: ColorCode::new(Color::Yellow, Color::Black),
        buffer: unsafe { &mut *(0xb8000 as *mut Buffer) },
    });
}

/// The standard color palette in VGA text mode.
#[allow(dead_code)]
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy, PartialEq, Eq)]
#[repr(u8)]
pub enum Color {
    Black = 0,
    Blue = 1,
    Green = 2,
    Cyan = 3,
    Red = 4,
    Magenta = 5,
    Brown = 6,
    LightGray = 7,
    DarkGray = 8,
    LightBlue = 9,
    LightGreen = 10,
    LightCyan = 11,
    LightRed = 12,
    Pink = 13,
    Yellow = 14,
    White = 15,
}

/// A combination of a foreground and a background color.
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy, PartialEq, Eq)]
#[repr(transparent)]
struct ColorCode(u8);

impl ColorCode {
    /// Create a new `ColorCode` with the given foreground and background colors.
    fn new(foreground: Color, background: Color) -> ColorCode {
        ColorCode((background as u8) << 4 | (foreground as u8))
    }
}

/// A screen character in the VGA text buffer, consisting of an ASCII character and a `ColorCode`.
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy, PartialEq, Eq)]
#[repr(C)]
struct ScreenChar {
    ascii_character: u8,
    color_code: ColorCode,
}

/// The height of the text buffer (normally 25 lines).
const BUFFER_HEIGHT: usize = 25;
/// The width of the text buffer (normally 80 columns).
const BUFFER_WIDTH: usize = 80;

/// A structure representing the VGA text buffer.
#[repr(transparent)]
struct Buffer {
    chars: [[Volatile<ScreenChar>; BUFFER_WIDTH]; BUFFER_HEIGHT],
}

/// A writer type that allows writing ASCII bytes and strings to an underlying `Buffer`.
///
/// Wraps lines at `BUFFER_WIDTH`. Supports newline characters and implements the
/// `core::fmt::Write` trait.
pub struct Writer {
    column_position: usize,
    color_code: ColorCode,
    buffer: &'static mut Buffer,
}

impl Writer {
    /// Writes an ASCII byte to the buffer.
    ///
    /// Wraps lines at `BUFFER_WIDTH`. Supports the `\n` newline character.
    pub fn write_byte(&mut self, byte: u8) {
        match byte {
            b'\n' => self.new_line(),
            byte => {
                if self.column_position >= BUFFER_WIDTH {
                    self.new_line();
                }

                let row = BUFFER_HEIGHT - 1;
                let col = self.column_position;

                let color_code = self.color_code;
                self.buffer.chars[row][col].write(ScreenChar {
                    ascii_character: byte,
                    color_code,
                });
                self.column_position += 1;
            }
        }
    }

    /// Writes the given ASCII string to the buffer.
    ///
    /// Wraps lines at `BUFFER_WIDTH`. Supports the `\n` newline character. Does **not**
    /// support strings with non-ASCII characters, since they can't be printed in the VGA text
    /// mode.
    fn write_string(&mut self, s: &str) {
        for byte in s.bytes() {
            match byte {
                // printable ASCII byte or newline
                0x20..=0x7e | b'\n' => self.write_byte(byte),
                // not part of printable ASCII range
                _ => self.write_byte(0xfe),
            }
        }
    }

    /// Shifts all lines one line up and clears the last row.
    fn new_line(&mut self) {
        for row in 1..BUFFER_HEIGHT {
            for col in 0..BUFFER_WIDTH {
                let character = self.buffer.chars[row][col].read();
                self.buffer.chars[row - 1][col].write(character);
            }
        }
        self.clear_row(BUFFER_HEIGHT - 1);
        self.column_position = 0;
    }

    /// Clears a row by overwriting it with blank characters.
    fn clear_row(&mut self, row: usize) {
        let blank = ScreenChar {
            ascii_character: b' ',
            color_code: self.color_code,
        };
        for col in 0..BUFFER_WIDTH {
            self.buffer.chars[row][col].write(blank);
        }
    }
}

impl fmt::Write for Writer {
    fn write_str(&mut self, s: &str) -> fmt::Result {
        self.write_string(s);
        Ok(())
    }
}

/// Like the `print!` macro in the standard library, but prints to the VGA text buffer.
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! print {
    ($($arg:tt)*) => ($crate::vga_buffer::_print(format_args!($($arg)*)));
}

/// Like the `println!` macro in the standard library, but prints to the VGA text buffer.
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! println {
    () => ($crate::print!("\n"));
    ($($arg:tt)*) => ($crate::print!("{}\n", format_args!($($arg)*)));
}

/// Prints the given formatted string to the VGA text buffer through the global `WRITER` instance.
#[doc(hidden)]
pub fn _print(args: fmt::Arguments) {
    use core::fmt::Write;
    WRITER.lock().write_fmt(args).unwrap();
}```
````

Comment: Do you have the file named exactly `cargo.toml`? If your filesystem is case-sensitive, that's not the same as `Cargo.toml`.

Comment: Yeah, its ``Cargo.toml`` I thought someone might catch it though didn't want to edit

Comment: Could you share the full `Cargo.toml` file and a minimal example of `main.rs`, then (probably with imports and an empty `fn main() {}` only)? I'm not sure what the problem is yet, and wouldn't want to simply guess.

Comment: Which version of rust, and which edition is the Cargo.toml configured for? If it's pre-2018, then you might be hitting issues due to a lack of `extern crate` (see https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/path-changes.html#no-more-extern-crate)

Comment: the editing thing is being fussy so give me a few minutes to put all the files on there please

Comment: @TomParker-Shemilt  The version is left blank as it started working when I removed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in the older versions of Rust, you had to explicitly declare every dependency crate with [`extern crate foo;`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/extern-crates.html) statements. This [became obsolete with 2018 edition](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/path-changes.html#no-more-extern-crate), but by default Cargo uses 2015 edition, in which `extern crate` is still mandatory.

Therefore, you have two ways to go:

- Add `edition = "2018"` (or even `edition = "2021"`) to the `[package]` section of `Cargo.toml`. This is probably the preferred way, since newer editions are generally more ergonomic and easier to use.
- Add `extern crate crate_name;` to the top of `main.rs` for each dependency.